# Error creating a simple class in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a class

```
export class ISlide {
    imageUrl: string;
    SongTitle: string;

    constructor(image: string, song: string) {
        this.imageUrl = image;
        this.SongTitle = song;
    }
}
```

later, I am trying to create an instance of this class, I have a statement

```
new ISlide("1", "1");
```

(there is no assignment for now, the creation line itself is the problem as its on statement).

And I get an error:

Failed to compile.

> slides.service.ts (39,17): 'ISlide' only refers to a type, but is
>   being used as a value here.

where line 39 of the slides.service.ts file is the above statement.

What am I doing wrong ? I have looked at couple of examples of creating a class in typescript and I think the code looks fine..

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ISlide%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20imageUrl%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SongTitle%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(image%3A%20string%2C%20song%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.imageUrl%20%3D%20image%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.SongTitle%20%3D%20song%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20ISlide(%221%22%2C%20%221%22)%3B) - you might need to post more of your code, or try to create a minimal reproduction of the issue.

Comment: My bet is that you are referencing something different then provided class.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11807

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Hermut was right, I had conflicting definitions of the same class